# How to make my Qt application on BeagleBone Black detect plugin "socketcan"

Tags: qt, qt5, beagleboneblack

So I have a working Qt installation on my BBB and I want to incorporate QtCanBus now in my application. I'm using this guide as starting point however whenever I run simple snippets, I get the error:

```
No such plugin: 'socketcan'
```

I already have compiled libs and plugins ready on BeagleBone and I also have these three commands exported to define environment variables for Qt.

```
export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/home/debian/Qt5ForBBB/lib/fonts
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/debian/Qt5ForBBB/plugins/platforms
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/debian/Qt5ForBBB/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Similar to second path for QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN, do we have same for canbus as I have compiled canbus libs in my QT5ForBBB/canbus folder?